# How to enable use of .htaccess in Apache on Ubuntu?

Tags: htaccess, apache2, ubuntu

I'm trying to enable use of *htaccess* file in Ubuntu 14.04 (Apache 2.4.7).
I know that this question has many possible duplicates, but none of them helped me yet.

### .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

### 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
AccessFileName .htaccess

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What else is needed?

Comment: The AllowOverride All directive allows all options in the .htaccess file. The 000-default.conf assumes that there is only one site on your server. Is the .htaccess file not working for you? Are there more than one site hosted on this server?

Comment: There are many folders in /var/www but no virtual hosts are created. /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder contains two files, 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf. htaccess file is located in /var/www/

Comment: Maybe 'DocumentRoot /var/www/'? (trailing slash)

Comment: Check to make sure /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ contains a link to 000-default.conf.   If you change the /var/www/index.html file you can see the changes when you view the server with a web browser, right?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### First Step

Open file as

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

### Second Step

remove comment sign (#) if you find it before this line ( line number 187 approx.)

`AccessFileName .htaccess`

### Third Step

Then find the line where there is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

replace "None" with "All"

```
AllowOverride All
```

And voila... `.htaccess` works!!

Comment: changes didn't take effect until I restarted apache Command: service apache restart

Comment: I suggest, as @TahirYasin mentions, restarting apache. `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 9):

Activate ModRewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: The `service` command is now the preferred way to restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*  remove comment sign (`#`) from `AccessFileName .htaccess`
2. The name of your Apache configuration file is not standard. You can rename it to *default.conf* in Windows and rename it to *default* in Linux. In Linux based OS run this code in terminal:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
   ```

Comment: It is named with the zeros so that it comes first alphabetically.  If you have a default.conf file and then create a site for anteater.com, then anteater becomes the default host because it gets loaded first.   Keep the 000 to prevent such problems.   The name of the conf file shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not .htaccess works.

Comment: 'AccessFileName .htaccess' is already uncommented. Above answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in
*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf* helped.

All other *.conf* files have already had `AllowOverride All`.