# IIS rewrite rules for SEO friendly URLs don't work in .htaccess for Apache

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using a Pi 3 for the Apache server but I can't figure out how to setup `.htaccess`. Previously I used IIS with which it is easy to implement SEO-friendly URLs.  Linux `.htaccess` is very different and I still can't figure it out.

First I created `.htaccess` in the root folder with the contents:

```
RewriteRule ^post/article\.php$    {C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$    post/article.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&id=$4
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml?$    sitemap.php
```

Which is supposed to make `example.in/?a=*,b=*,c=*,id=*` shown as `example.in/a/b/c/id`.  However, that never happens.

Then I tried these changes to the virtual host.  Do I have to change the configuration in the virtual host to get it to work?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Documentroot /------
    ServerName example.in
    ServerAlias www.example.in
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^post/article\.php$    {C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$    post/article.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&id=$4
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml?$    sitemap.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Is anyone able to suggest how can I put rewrite so it actually works?

I also follow guide [How to enable use of .htaccess in Apache on Ubuntu?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu#61022) but I could not get it to work.

Comment: `{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}` - That's an IIS thing. I assume here you are trying to canonicalise any direct request for `/post/article.php?a=` etc.? `^sitemap\.xml?$` - I assume the trailing `l` should not be optional?

Comment: "I use IIS which is totally easy to complete SEO-friendly tag" - Nooo, Apache is better! ;)

Comment: easy to implement you just mention your link there and it just do it itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^post/article\.php$    {C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$    post/article.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&id=$4
> RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml?$    sitemap.php
> ```

If used in `.htaccess` these directives would result in a malformed internal rewrite - possibly a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error response).

If used in a *VirtualHost* context they simply won't match so won't actually do anything.

#### In the `<VirtualHost>`

To write this in a VirtualHost context (not `.htaccess`), you would need to do it like the following instead...

Note that if you have implemented an SSL cert and are using HTTPS *only* (ie. redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container) then these directives need to go in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container. The `<VirtualHost *:80>` can be relatively empty.

Your 2nd rule is close as you are really just missing some slash prefixes and flags.

In a *server* or *virtualhost* context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is always the full root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash. And the *substitution* string (target URL) cannot be relative.

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests for "/post/article.php?a=<a>&b=<b>&c=<c>&id=<id>"
# to the canonical URL: "/<a>/<b>/<c>/<id>"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)\s
RewriteRule ^/post/article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/%4 [QSD,NE,R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/<a>/<b>/<c>/<id>" to the underlying filesystem path
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /post/article.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&id=$4 [L]

# Rewrite "/sitemap.xml" to "/sitemap.php"
RewriteRule ^/(sitemap)\.xml$ /$1.php [L]
```

The `NE` flag may be required on the first rule if you have any %-encoded values in the query string, in order to prevent these from being doubly encoded when redirecting to the corresponding URL-path.

The `QSD` flag discards the query string from the initial request, otherwise, the query string is copied through to the target.

The `%1` - `%4` backreferences contain the values of the captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` directive).

#### In `.htaccess`

To do this in `.htaccess` you first need to enable `.htaccess` overrides in the VirtualHost using the `AllowOverride` directive - otherwise the `.htaccess` file is going to be ignored. (And note the spelling, you've spelt it wrong 3 times in your question, in varying ways.)

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.in
    ServerAlias www.example.in

    DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root

    <Directory /path/to/document/root>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in `.htaccess` you can write the directives as follows. They are very similar, except there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and the *substitution* string also does not need the slash prefix.

In a *directory* or *`.htaccess`* context, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is less the directory-prefix so never starts with a slash. And the *substitution* string (target URL) can be a relative filesystem path.

For example, in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests for "/post/article.php?a=<a>&b=<b>&c=<c>&id=<id>"
# to the canonical URL: "/<a>/<b>/<c>/<id>"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)&c=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)\s
RewriteRule ^post/article\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/%4 [QSD,NE,R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/<a>/<b>/<c>/<id>" to the underlying filesystem path
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ post/article.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&id=$4 [L]

# Rewrite "/sitemap.xml" to "/sitemap.php"
RewriteRule ^(sitemap)\.xml$ $1.php [L]
```

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: still having no result I was try most of thing that you mention try with log so caught any error in acess.log or error.log but nothing again  but due to your answer and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa give me some direction

Comment: I have to use it on 443 port that is where first i go wrong

Comment: Yes, if you have an SSL cert installed and using HTTPS _only_ then this needs to be in the `<VirtualHost *:443>`, not port 80. (The vHost for port 80 should then be a simple redirect to HTTPS.) If you are using `.htaccess` then this is not relevant.